# How to order a collection with LINQ so that a particular string appears first

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an array of string values, `{ "Jools", "Jops", "Stoo", "RJ" }`

I want to order it so that `"Jops"` is first in the list, but I don't care what order the other values are in. It's also possible for multiple values, so all instances of `"Jops"` should appear first.

Is there an easy way to do this with LINQ?

Comment: Jops never comes before Jools... well, unless it's over his dead body ;-) Man I loved that game. +1 for the memories.

Comment: Why do you want to have Jobs first, because of alphabetical order? Or just Jops sould be always first?

Comment: My actual data is a bunch of types, one of the types is primary and the rest are all misc. I wanted to show the primary one first, and the rest in any order

Comment: I'm sure I've answered this somewhere before but can't find the actual question... :)

Comment: @Chris Reminds me of the Dara O'Brien sketch, "Do you know the capital of Mongolia?" "Yes, I do." "I was kind of hoping for the city name", "That's not what you asked now is it!"

Comment: Seems like it's a duplicate but the duplicate question title is a bit pants. No wonder I didn't find it when I searched!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about

```
var values = new string[] { "Jools", "Jops", "Stoo", "RJ" };
var sortedValues = values.OrderByDescending(s => s.Equals("Jops"));
```

Simply sort by whether it is the value you want or not.

Edited to mention a very valuable point in the comments below, the remaining items are not sorted by this mechanism. To guarantee their order use the ThenBy( ) method.

Comment: Presumably that iterates and evaluates true, false, false, false and orders it based on that?

Comment: I'd note that this will make the rest non-deterministic, to solve that an additional `ThenBy` can sort the rest. Or to put it all in one call to `OrderBy`, use the overload that takes an `IComparer`.

Comment: It works the other way around :)

Comment: @BartoszKP you are absolutely right - fixed!

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth That's significant: sorts can do odd things if given inconsistent results from comparisons (eg. A > B but in the next comparison B > A). But rather than using `ThenBy` have a comparator that delegates to the default when neither value is "Jools".

Answer (score 1):

I would recomment to use a sorted list and write your own Comparer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `"Jops"` hard coded then this will do:

```
var result = values
    .Where(x => x == "Jops")
    .Concat(values.Where(x => x != "Jops"));
```

A shorter version:

```
var result = values
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Equals("Jops"));
```